# KM Development/Testing Environment

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I run Gentoo, and I compile an out-of-tree network kernel module on the host OS where I have a full dev environment. I then copy those kernel modules over to the KVM'd guest OS's where I load and test them.

The problem is, I have to make a few minor changes to header files to the kernel sources each time I upgrade the kernel on both the host OS and the guest OS because I compile on the host OS and run on the guest OS. I also need to make sure the host and guest are running the same kernel version, however, there are minor differences in built in modules (I.e. the host OS is setup for virtualization, video, etc... whereas the guest OS's are slightly different to include serial consoles that output the ring buffer to the host OS). So mostly it's the same .config from the host and I copy this to the guest.

My biggest concern is that I'm wondering if that could possibly have an effect on the stability/testing of my KM's since I compile on one, and run on the other. I haven't had major problems doing this and I'm guessing the times when my stuff oops, I've found so far it's been my code.

I don't have a full dev environment within my guest OS's because I put alot of effort in customizing my desktop and the scripts/tools and such that I run on it. My guest OS's are minimal Gentoo installs that only have the tools I need to test and debug.

So that's how I do it and I'm wondering if more experienced devs have a better way of doing kernel develpment/testing and simpler ways of getting by the kernel upgrades.